# Accessing the database on the server with a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, database, server, windows-services

I wrote a windows service that detects usb drives plugged into the computer.I can get data such as computer IP address, transaction date, usb name, plugged and unplugged warning.My goal is to monitor usb movements on computers in the local network.For this I need to maintain a database on a server in the local network.I want this database to be updated when usb is plugged into any computer.How can I do this in a local network specific? What are the steps to follow?I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Are you asking how to set up and use a database?

Comment: Even general suggestions on how to do it will do the trick. What should I research? Using what can I achieve this? Now I'm trying to do it using Microsoft sql server management. Then I will try to share the database on the local network.  @TheGeneral

Comment: Yes many databases will allow you to connect to them over a local network. Sql server is on of them

Comment: What have you already tried? The question seems a little bit vague the way that it's written because you're describing many challenges at once: setting up the local server, mounting a DB, connecting to the DB from your custom software, and so on. You may need to write software that interfaces with the DB rather than having your utility talk to it directly. I think what you're talking about is how to build an API backend that communicates with a database.